# Change featured.tpl add quantity & product options in opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

How to add quantity and any other product options in featured.tpl and latest.tpl,special.tpl?

Normally product options couldn't show on featured.tpl, Latest.tpl and special.tpl.. but I want to show quantity and any other options. Or tell me any other options in opencart admin panel..

Comment: there are no way to do this from admin, you have to modify the code of each controller for featured, latest etc & also .tpl file as well.

Comment: can u explain or show some example for this?  i can edit featured.php,latest.php cotroller files and .tpl files which line i can edit or add some code can u show image explaination?